# Cannot set fringe foreground color

Tags: faces, customize, fringe

I want to change the foreground color of my fringes, in [my theme file](https://github.com/fleutot/.emacs.d/blob/master/themes/bisque-darker-theme.el).

I changed (line 84):

```
- `(fringe ((t (:foreground ,bisque-fg :background ,bisque-bg))))
```

to

```
+ `(fringe ((t (:foreground ,bisque-red :background ,bisque-bg))))
                                    ^^^
```

Then with `customize-group` I removed what was manually changed. Now, the `sample` field for `Fringe` in the customize window reflects the `bisque-red` color in my theme file.

---

This is the result:

[image]

The foreground color *is* honored, but what the foreground is isn't what I expected.

The line continuation arrows *have* the foreground color I set.

What I want is to change the color of the *vertical line itself*.

---

<s>I even manually removed the `fringe`-related things in the `custom-set-faces` section of my init file.</s>

However when I load the theme (or start a new emacs), the fringes still have the default foreground face color.

If I do the same thing with the fringes' background color, all works well.

Something takes precedence over the foreground color of the fringes, although Customize shows the right one. What is it? How do I make sure the fringe foreground in my theme file works?

Comment: Have you tried loading the theme after starting emacs with `emacs -q`?

Comment: Good call, you made me aware of what the foreground color of fringes actually are. Edited accordingly, and found my answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought the window separators used the fringes' foreground color. They don't.

The fringe foreground color is for continuation lines in the fringe.

The face I was trying to change is `vertical-border`.

This in my theme:

```
`(vertical-border ((t (:foreground ,bisque-fg-2))))
```

(with `(bisque-fg-2 "#5f5549")`) gave what I wanted (a darker separator):

[image]